# d3 xAxis with ordinal scale and a click event?

Tags: d3.js

I will build a chart with an x-axis (ordinal scale). Every label at the axis have a click event. The data for the x-Axis Labels are stored in JSON objects (xAxisData.*Label*) - my xscale.domain. But when I click on a label, I need the ID from the json object (but my data domain are only the Labels). So how can I store the *ID* additional to the *Label* ? thx....!!

```
xAxisData: {
              ID: 1,
              TimeStamp: 01.01.2014 00::00,
              Label: "00:15",
            },

xAxisLabels = d3.set(xAxisData.map(function (d) { return d.Label; })).values(); 

xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeBands([0, chartWidth], 0.1)
            .xScale.domain(xAxisLabels);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the objects themselves as input to the domain:

```
xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeBands([0, chartWidth], 0.1)
        .xScale.domain(xAxisData);
```

Then, to get the `Label` as label, use the `.tickFormat()` function of your axis:

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
          .tickFormat(function(d) { return d.Label; });
```

Now the data bound to the ticks includes everything and you can use `d.ID` in your event handler.

**Update**

This doesn't quite work as expected because D3 coerces the domain values into strings and maps them to the scale indices. This doesn't work in this case, as objects are always coerced to the same value. A quick fix is to specify the stringification yourself (i.e. convert to JSON) and take care of the necessary conversions behind the scenes:

```
xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(data.map(JSON.stringify))
            .rangeBands([0, w], 0.1); // 1%

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
         .scale(xScale)
         .tickFormat(function (d) {
             return JSON.parse(d).label;
         })
         .orient("bottom");
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VjR89/4/).

Comment: Hi Lars, thx for your answer! Are you sure the tickFormat works with an ordinal scale? I get only one value in `.tickFormat(function(d) { return d.Label; });` - but my dataset has more values ?

Comment: Yes, the function is executed for each label.

Comment: hmm.. unfortunately this does not work for me, what am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/VjR89/2/

Comment: You were passing an array of arrays to `.domain()` instead of just the array, but I was also mistaken about being able to use objects -- I'll update the answer with a working solution.